# Get text as database string value Angular

Tags: html, angular, string

I'd like to have my text as it is save in database, per exemple :

[image: database screen]

in HTML it is like this :

[image: html screen]

My HTML code is:

```
<mat-card class="message-on-right" *ngIf="isAuthor(message)" [style.border-color]="message?.color">
        <mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-title>
                {{message?.authorName}}
            </mat-card-title>
            <mat-card-subtitle>{{message?.date | date:'EEEE, dd/MM/yyyy, HH:mm'}}</mat-card-subtitle>
        </mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-content *ngIf="!allRead(message)">{{message?.corpus}}</mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-content *ngIf="allRead(message)" class="content-read">{{message?.corpus}}</mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-actions>
            <mat-checkbox *ngFor="let desti of message.destinations" [disabled]="disabledCheck(desti?.userName,desti?.hasRead)" [checked]="desti.hasRead" (change)="hasRead(desti,message?.id)">{{desti?.userName}}</mat-checkbox>
        </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
```

I already tried [innerHTML] and other things I saw on stackoverflow, but nothing works.

My C# getter in backend is:

```
[HttpGet("fromfor/{userName}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<MessageDTO>>> GetMessagesFromForUsers(string userName)
    {
        var messages = await _context.Messages.ToListAsync();
        var messagesToReturn = new List<Message>();
        var destinations = await _context.Destinations.ToListAsync();
        var user = await _context.Users.Where(u => u.Pseudo == userName).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        if (messages == null)
            return NotFound();
        else
        {
            foreach (Message m in messages)
            {
                if (m.AuthorName == userName)
                    messagesToReturn.Add(m);
            }
        }
        if (destinations == null)
            return NotFound();
        else
        {
            foreach (Destination d in destinations)
            {
                if (d.UserName == userName)
                {
                    var mess = await _context.Messages.Where(m => m.Id == d.MessageId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
                    messagesToReturn.Add(mess);
                }
            }
        }

        return messagesToReturn.ToDTO();

    }
```

Maybe there is a function to take string as they are in DB but I don't know it, s tnkans in advance for helping me !

Comment: How does that date arrive in your raw json response?

Comment: @MikeOne what do you mean ?

Comment: Like how I send it from backend ? Or how I declare it in front ?